# adding new rows to an existing csv after filtering

Tags: powershell

Source file:

```
"SampleNumber","TypeIndicator","ResultName","Indicator","ResultEntry"
"111","10","S","","125.234"
"111","10","Sn","","0.034"
"111","10","Mo","","0.307"
"111","10","Cr ","u","0.022"
"111","10","Sb","u","-0.096"
"111","10","P","","1.593"
"111","10","Zn","","0.126"
"111","ND","S","o","113.920"
"111","ND","Sn","","0.019"
"111","ND","Mo","","0.278"
"111","ND","Cr ","","0.003"
"111","ND","Sb","","0.008"
"111","ND","P","","1.445"
"111","ND","Zn","","0.045"
```

Based on rules (commented in code below) the file will be filtered and a new row added for each ResultName.

Code

```
$fileData = Import-Csv $file.FullName | 
    Group-Object ResultName | Foreach-Object {
        $Ten = $_.Group | Where-Object { $_.TypeIndicator -eq '10' }
        $ND = $_.Group | Where-Object { $_.TypeIndicator -eq 'ND' }

        # Case 1: If Indicator is null or ! for /10 and Indicator is null or ! for ND  
        #         Select line ND and create new row with ResultName + estimated Eg."Al estimated" with ResultEntry = ''
        if(('!','' -contains $Ten.Indicator) -and ('!','' -contains $ND.Indicator)) {
            $ND

            #create new row
            $newRow = New-Object PsObject -Property @{'SampleNumber' = $ND.SampleNumber; 'TypeIndicator'= $ND.TypeIndicator;
                                                        'ResultName' = $ND.ResultName + ' estimated' ;
                                                        'Indicator'=$ND.Indicator ; 'ResultEntry'='' } 

        #Case 2: If Indicator is null/! for 10 and Indicator is not null for ND. 
        # Select line ND and create new row with ResultName + estimated Eg."Al estimated" with ResultEntry = ''
        } elseif (('!','' -contains $Ten.Indicator) -and ('o','u' -contains $ND.Indicator)) {
            $Ten
            $newRow = New-Object PsObject -Property @{'SampleNumber' =  $Ten.SampleNumber; 'TypeIndicator'=  $Ten.TypeIndicator;
                                                        'ResultName' =  $Ten.ResultName + ' estimated' ;
                                                        'Indicator'= $Ten.Indicator ; 'ResultEntry'='' }  
        }

            #Case 3: If Indicator contains either 'o' or 'u' for 10 and Indicateur is null/! for ND 
            # select line ND and create a new row with ResultEntry = ''
        elseif (('o','u' -contains $Ten.Indicator) -and ('!','' -contains $ND.Indicator)) {
            $ND  
            $newRow = New-Object PsObject -Property @{'SampleNumber' = $ND.SampleNumber; 'TypeIndicator'= $ND.TypeIndicator;
                                                        'ResultName' = $ND.ResultName;
                                                        'Indicator'=$ND.Indicator ; 'ResultEntry'='' }   
        }

        #Case 4: If both /10 and ND contains either o or u, Select line /10
            # select line 10 and create a new row with ResultEntry = ''
        elseif (('u','o' -contains $Ten.Indicator) -and ('o','u' -contains $ND.Indicator)) {
            $Ten

            $newRow = New-Object PsObject -Property @{'SampleNumber' = $Ten.SampleNumber; 'TypeIndicator'= $Ten.TypeIndicator;
                                                        'ResultName' = $Ten.ResultName;
                                                        'Indicator'=$Ten.Indicator ; 'ResultEntry'='' }  
        }

        Write-Host $newRow #PROBLEM HERE: I dont know how to get this $newRow appended to my $fileData
```

HERE: I dont know how to get this $newRow appended to my $fileData

Sample desired output :
[image]

**Question**
How can I append the $newRow variable to the $fileData inorder to export all values out to file?

Comment: `Export-CSV -Append`?

Comment: but the $newRow must be included with the $fileData before export. Or I export-csv each $newRow and then export $fileData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Write-Host $newRow` simply output the new object `$newRow` to append it to $filedata.
BTW your code is hardly readable, I'll enhance it.

With your above sample data this code:

```
$file = gci "q:\test\2018\03\27\sample.*"
$fileData = Import-Csv $file.FullName | Group-Object ResultName | Foreach-Object {
    $Ten = $_.Group | Where-Object { $_.TypeIndicator -eq '10' }
    $ND =  $_.Group | Where-Object { $_.TypeIndicator -eq 'ND' }

    # Case 1: If Indicator is null or ! for /10 and Indicator is null or ! for ND  
    #         Select line ND and create new row with ResultName + estimated Eg."Al estimated" with ResultEntry = ''
    if(('!','' -contains $Ten.Indicator) -and ('!','' -contains $ND.Indicator)) {
        $ND

        #create new row
        $newRow = New-Object PsObject -Property @{'SampleNumber' = $ND.SampleNumber;
                                                  'TypeIndicator'= $ND.TypeIndicator;
                                                  'ResultName'   = $ND.ResultName + ' estimated' ;
                                                  'Indicator'    = $ND.Indicator ; 
                                                  'ResultEntry'  = '' 
                                                 } 

    #Case 2: If Indicator is null/! for 10 and Indicator is not null for ND. 
    # Select line ND and create new row with ResultName + estimated Eg."Al estimated" with ResultEntry = ''
    } elseif (('!','' -contains $Ten.Indicator) -and ('o','u' -contains $ND.Indicator)) {
        $Ten
        $newRow = New-Object PsObject -Property @{'SampleNumber' = $Ten.SampleNumber; 
                                                  'TypeIndicator'= $Ten.TypeIndicator;
                                                  'ResultName'   = $Ten.ResultName + ' estimated' ;
                                                  'Indicator'    = $Ten.Indicator ; 
                                                  'ResultEntry'  = '' 
                                                  }  
    }

     #Case 3: If Indicator contains either 'o' or 'u' for 10 and Indicateur is null/! for ND 
     # select line ND and create a new row with ResultEntry = ''
    elseif (('o','u' -contains $Ten.Indicator) -and ('!','' -contains $ND.Indicator)) {
        $ND  
        $newRow = New-Object PsObject -Property @{'SampleNumber'  = $ND.SampleNumber; 
                                                   'TypeIndicator'= $ND.TypeIndicator;
                                                   'ResultName'   = $ND.ResultName;
                                                   'Indicator'    = $ND.Indicator ; 
                                                   'ResultEntry'  = '' 
                                                  }   
    }

     #Case 4: If both /10 and ND contains either o or u, Select line /10
     # select line 10 and create a new row with ResultEntry = ''
    elseif (('u','o' -contains $Ten.Indicator) -and ('o','u' -contains $ND.Indicator)) {
        $Ten

        $newRow = New-Object PsObject -Property @{'SampleNumber' = $Ten.SampleNumber; 
                                                  'TypeIndicator'= $Ten.TypeIndicator;
                                                  'ResultName'   = $Ten.ResultName;
                                                  'Indicator'    = $Ten.Indicator ; 
                                                  'ResultEntry'  = '' 
                                                 }  
    }
    $newRow
    # Write-Host $newRow #PROBLEM HERE: I dont know how to get this $newRow appended to my $fileData 
}
$fileData | Format-Table
```

will give you this output:

```
SampleNumber TypeIndicator ResultName   Indicator ResultEntry
------------ ------------- ----------   --------- -----------
111          10            S                      125.234
111          10            S estimated
111          ND            Sn                     0.019
111          ND            Sn estimated
111          ND            Mo                     0.278
111          ND            Mo estimated
111          ND            Cr                     0.003
111          ND            Cr
111          ND            Sb                     0.008
111          ND            Sb
111          ND            P                      1.445
111          ND            P estimated
111          ND            Zn                     0.045
111          ND            Zn estimated
```

Comment: I wrapped the above code in a foreach loop ($foreach $file in $files) {$fileData =  import-csv ...} but I seem to be getting only the last value in my file

Comment: Simplest (but maybe inefficient) way could be to use `foreach ($file in $files) {$fileData += import-csv ...} `